# In java "string" == "string" is false why?

Tags: java

The following statement appears in Section [3.10.5. String Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5JLS) of the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html):

> A string literal always refers to the same instance of class String.
>   This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings that are
>   the values of constant expressions (§15.28) - are "interned" so as to
>   share unique instances, using the method String.intern.

I am using Java JDK 7 and Eclipse indigo.

and my test program is as follows:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "string";
        String s2 = "string";

        System.out.print(s1 == s2); // true
        System.out.print(" , " + "string" == "string"); // false
    }

}
```

Comment: s1.equals(s2)  ,,,String is not primitive data type

Comment: `==` compares objects. If you want to compare their contents, use `equals` or `compareTo`.

Comment: Yes, I know about using `equals(...)` to compare strings. I'm asking why specifically in this case my program does not exhibit behaviour which matches the JLS.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is an operator precedence issue.  The `==` operator has a lower precedence than the `+` operator.

What you are actually testing is whether `(" , " + "string")` is equal to `"string"`.  It isn't.

If you mean that to compare `"string"` and `"string"` you should write:

```
    System.out.print(" , " + ("string" == "string"));
```

---

The standard advice of not using `==` to test strings applies too ... but that's not what is giving you the confusing output.

Comment: Wow, how on earth did you figure that out?

Comment: @JRL - it is operator precedence, not the left to right rule that matters here.  (Try `print("string" == "string" + " , ")` )

Comment: @leftbrain - just 30+ years of programming experience :-).  There's also the BIG clue that the program will output `"truefalse"` rather than `"true , false"`.

Comment: @StephenC - seriously, this is the best comment I've seen for weeks.

Answer (score 8):

That's all operator precedence. The second check is:

```
" , " + "string" == "string"
```

Which is:

```
(" , " + "string") == "string"
```

Which is of course false.

Answer (score 3):

Because `+` has a higher precedence than `==`. If the code is rewritten like

```
System.out.print(" , " + ("string" == "string"));
```

it displays `true` as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Its is adding comma ',' to the first string and then equal operator is applied. + has higher precedence than == and it is Left to Right.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the ", " is being concatenated to "string" **before** the equals operator is being applied.

Answer (score 0):

If you compare Strings with '==' you will always get true ... it compares objects, not "content" ... string IS a string ... you cannot get false in that case... but with method equals() you can check if the content of 2 strings is, well, equal.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm afraid you are mistaken. As a learning exercise execute the following code and see what you get `System.out.print("A" == "B");` or `System.out.print(new String("A") == new String("A"))`. They're both String objects so according to your statement the result of executing that code should be `true`. *hint* it is not true. You might want to read section 3.10.5. String Literals  from the Java Language Specification.